# PyQt / Qt Designer: keeping elements together

Tags: pyqt, qt-designer

I'm putting together a widget in PyQt's Qt Designer, but struggling to make elements that should stay as close to each other as possible do so after applying a grid layout.

For example, in this layout, I've set the question mark (which acts as the tooltip) to be 2 px from the right hand edge of each of the input elements:

[image]

When I apply a grid layout, these spaces massively (and inconsistently across all 3 lines) increase:

[image]

I've tried applying a horizontal layout to the rows of elements, but even this causes the elements to spread out more horizontally in an inconsistent manner.

Am I missing something obvious? Is there a way to force elements to stay a certain distance for neighbouring elements?

**EDIT / UPDATE**

Thanks to [three_pineapples' suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23993746/pyqt-qt-designer-keeping-elements-together?noredirect=1#comment36975296_23993746), I've put some horizontal-spacers in (although I'm not sure if I've done it in the way he intended?)

[image]

This has solved it to some extent, but:

- the gap between elements and the question mark is now consistent, but 6 px on all rows!
- the gap between other elements is not consistent (the gap between the `QLineEdit` and the File Browse button is 12 px, not the 5 that I intended here)
- the height of the spacers are the same height as the rows, but QtDesigner seems to have added in a weird orphaned row above the file select row. Although I'm sure it's nothing to be concerned about I do prefer to understand how things work and why it's doing it...

Comment: Have you investigated putting "horizontal spacers" in the right most cell of each row? (you'd need to add another column to the middle row)

Comment: @three_pineapples I've had a go at this, see edit for info!

Comment: Cool, it might help if you could post a link to the ui file as well so we can see how you have layed everything out

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling [setSpacing(0)](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlayout.html#spacing-prop) on the QGridLayout to reduce the spacing between items? (there's also setHorizontalSpacing(x) and setVerticalSpacing(y) if you prefer). Also, [setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlayout.html#setContentsMargins) would eliminate the outer margins on the grid, which I think is not what you're looking for here but might be related or useful for someone stumbling upon this.

Snippet:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class MyClass(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        p1 = QtGui.QPushButton('One', self)
        p2 = QtGui.QPushButton('Two', self)
        p3 = QtGui.QPushButton('Three', self)
        p4 = QtGui.QPushButton('Four', self)
        grid = QtGui.QGridLayout(self)
        grid.addWidget(p1, 0, 0)
        grid.addWidget(p2, 0, 1)
        grid.addWidget(p3, 1, 0)
        grid.addWidget(p4, 1, 1)
        grid.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)  # this seems to be the outer padding of the grid
        grid.setHorizontalSpacing(0)  # I think this is what you're looking for
        grid.setVerticalSpacing(0)
        # grid.setSpacing(0)  # this would set vertical & horizontal spacing at once
        self.setLayout(grid)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyClass()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I'm not used to using QtDesigner but there should be ways of setting these properties there, if you prefer.